# Socket.IO connection to Mac

Tags: android, node.js, macos, kotlin, socket.io

I want to create a simple `Socket.IO` connection between my `Mac` and `Android phone`. It works correctly when I connect an android emulator (by providing localhost address), but when I try to connect a real device (it's on the same Wi-Fi) it just doesn't work. Is there any setting, I should enable on my Mac to allow devices to connect to it?

My server code :

```java
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1337);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Someone just connected!");

    // Echo back messages from the client
    socket.on('image', function (message) {
        console.log("Got image of length: " + message.length);
        socket.emit('image', message);
    });
});
```

My Android Client code:

```java
 private fun connectToServer() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.5:1337/") // 10.0.2.2 for Emulator
            socket.on("connect", connected)
            startConnection = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            socket.connect()
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

  private val connected: Emitter.Listener = Emitter.Listener {
        Log.d("AndroidClient", "Connection time: ${SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startConnection}")
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that you are tring access your computer, via Wifi, if your computer and mobile device on the same network, that I guess it is a firewall issue in your computer (server) OR your local firewall router.

Comment: I've quickly written similar socket client in Flutter and.. it works. Both on emulator and on real device. So it is not problem with my Wi-Fi / Mac settings or router etc.. is there a bug in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a while, I resolved it. It seems like, under the hood Flutter adds special security policy which has to be added on our own in Android app, to allow connections via HTTP instead of HTTPS. I've used solution 2 of [this](https://better-coding.com/solved-android-cannot-send-data-to-the-server-cleartext-communication-to-not-permitted-by-network-security-policy/).